django OAuth Toolkit not getting redirect URI
I am using Django OAuth toolkit and using the following code for OAuth implementation
import requests
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import AuthenticationForm, UserProfileForm
from .models import UserProfile
from oauth2_provider.models import get_application_model
import base64

Application = get_application_model()

def oauth_login(request):
    app = Application.objects.get(name="App")
    #redirect_uri = request.GET.get("redirect_uri", "http://test.com:8000/callback")
    #redirect_uri = request.GET.get("redirect_uri", "http://test.com:8002/malicious_redirect.html")
    redirect_uri = request.POST.get("redirect_uri", "http://test.com:8002/malicious_redirect.html")
    
    authorization_url = (
        f"http://test.com:8000/o/authorize/?client_id={app.client_id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}"
    )
    return redirect(authorization_url)

def oauth_callback(request):
    code = request.GET.get("code")
    
    if not code:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'missing_code', 'details': 'Missing code parameter.'}, status=400) 

    token_url = "http://test.com:8000/o/token/"
    client_id = Application.objects.get(name="App").client_id
    client_secret = Application.objects.get(name="App").client_secret
    #redirect_uri = request.GET.get("redirect_uri", "http://test.com:8002/callback")
    redirect_uri = request.GET.get("redirect_uri", "http://test.com:8002/unique_redirect.html")
    
    data = {
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "code": code,
        "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
        "client_id": client_id,
        "client_secret": client_secret,
    }
    
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': f'Basic {base64.b64encode(f"{client_id}:{client_secret}".encode()).decode()}',
    }
    
    response = requests.post(token_url, data=data, headers=headers)
    tokens = response.json()
    print(tokens)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'token_exchange_failed', 'details': tokens}, status=response.status_code)
    
    request.session['access_token'] = tokens['access_token']
    request.session['refresh_token'] = tokens['refresh_token']
    
    return JsonResponse(tokens)
    #return redirect('profile')

The problem is that if I am logged into the OAuth 2.0 admin panel with superuser credentials, the above code works fine and redirects to the provided URL. Otherwise it doesn't work and uses the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile/' from settings.py.
What could be the reason?

@AndrewYim thanks for response.I've added imports, but I am not sure if I am logged in to the admin panel, it works, but otherwise, it doesn't consider the parameter redirect_uri. The parameter redirect_uri is also listed in the client application valid redirections

Bit disappointed not to get support on the forum regarding a basic query :(

I think most of the users are on holidays. This is the only explanation, because activity dropped significantly in July.

hope you are doing good. I'm not an expert on the matter nor I've the means to test this out for my self, but let me give you a few suggestions that might help resolve the problem.

The first thing that comes to mind is that as the Django OAuth Toolkit sometimes perform an authorization check before allowing the redirect. So when you're logged in as a superuser, you have full permissions, which is why it works. For other users, it might be failing this check.
Just to be safe you should also ensure that the redirect_uri you're using is exactly matching one of the URIs listed in the client application's valid redirections.
I don't think this would've been neglected but still check if the user has the specific scope permissions (if you've defined scopes that is.)
Oh, and you can also have a proper look in session handling that you might've done because when not logged in as a superuser, the application might be losing the session information and defaulting to the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL

I suggest doing the following to pin point the problem:
Log the redirect_uri at various points to ensure it's being passed correctly.
Review your settings.py file to ensure that the OAuth toolkit is configured correctly and also specially check the OAUTH2_PROVIDER settings.
You can also consider implementing a custom login view that uses Django's authentication system.

You can try something like this, to check where exactly your the flow is breaking for non-superusers:
@login_required
def oauth_login(request):
    app = Application.objects.get(name="App")
    redirect_uri = request.POST.get("redirect_uri", "http://test.com:8002/malicious_redirect.html")
    
    print(f"User: {request.user}, Redirect URI: {redirect_uri}")
    
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        raise PermissionDenied("User must be authenticated")
    
    print(f"Cleared authentication check.")
    
    authorization_url = (
        f"http://test.com:8000/o/authorize/?client_id={app.client_id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}"
    )
    print(f"Authorization URL: {authorization_url}")
    return redirect(authorization_url)

And as a last resort you can look into the Django OAuth Toolkit's source code, particularly the AuthorizationView class, to see how it handles redirects and authentication.

As I'm unable to test these out myself, I can only provide with some suggestions that you might've already tried, I apologize if this is not much of a help.
still a good luck to you, and 'hope you get to solve your problem. 
